# Use the definition of a limit to prove directly that $1$ is not a limit of the sequence $1/n$

Tags: limits

I'm not sure where to start with this. I was thinking of assuming $1$ is a limit and arriving at a contradiction?

Comment: that is the easiest approach! You just have to write down the definition of limit and plug in 1 as the limit. Show the definition doesn't hold!

Comment: @RSerrao Oh true, that's probably best.

Comment: You mean you want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\neq1$? Or what?

Comment: Or you could just show that $0$ is a limit of $1/n$ and quote the uniquness of the limit (in a metric space)

Answer (score 2):

$1$ is not a limit point of the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ because $|1-\frac{1}{n}|\geq 1/2$ for all $n\geq 2$. So taking $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ there is no $N$ such that $|1-\frac{1}{m}|<\epsilon$ for all $m\geq N$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon=1/2$ we have that
 $$|1-n^{-1}|\geq\epsilon$$
for $n\geq 2$.